# data pooling in jsp

Tags: java, database, jsp, hosting

Hello I have developed a small website in plain JSP without using Servlets.I have hosted the website at Eatj.com.All webpages are running properly.But database is not connected.My database is in MS-Access and I am using simple JDBC:ODBC connection.After reserch on internet I found out that I need to pool my data using DBConnector.I am new to pooling I tried it but in vain,so can i get any guidance?

my jsp code :

```
<body>
 <%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
  <%@page import ="javax.sql.*"%>
 <%
 String name=request.getParameter("name");
String email=request.getParameter("email");
String comment=request.getParameter("comment");
try{
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
DBConnector dbConnector= DBConnector.getInstance("jdbc:odbc://localhost/prakashd22?autoReconnect=true","prakashd22","*******");
Connection con = dbConnector.getConnection();
ResultSet rs = null;

Statement st = con.createStatement();

String sql = ("INSERT INTO feedback VALUES ('" + name + "','" + email + "','"+ comment +"') ");
st.executeUpdate(sql);
rs.close();
st.close();
con.close();
}
catch(Exception e){}
%>
<script language="javascript">
alert("Thank you for your feedback");
</script>
<jsp:include page="../page/feed.jsp"/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at some of the open source alternatives that aim to solve this problem. For example: http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/

Check out some code samples to inspire you: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/dbcp/trunk/doc/

Lastly, I'd suggest to put as little code in the JSP as possible and move it to some class. That way the code will be much easier to test, reuse and maintain.

Comment: thanks for help but this my high school assignment and i have to do this as shown above.So is there any other way of hosting website for trial period with simple JDBC:ODBC dsn connection?